# MS Access Join Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to combine columns of two queries as follows:
I'm looking for an Access solution.

```
Query1:                 Query2:
-------------           -------------
Col1   Col2             ColA   ColB
-------------           -------------
314      2              314     1
314      3              314     7
314      4              314     3
314      5              314     8

Desired Output:
Col1   Col2   ColB
314      5      8
314      4      7
314      3      3
314      2      1
```

I tried inner join:

```
SELECT Query1.col1, Query1.col2, Query2.colB
FROM Query2 INNER JOIN Query1 ON Query2.colA = Query1.col1;
```

But I'm getting this undesired output:

```
Undesired output:
Col1 Col2 ColB
314   4 1
314   5 1
314   2 1
314   3 1
314   4 7
314   5 7
314   2 7
314   3 7
314   4 3
314   5 3
314   2 3
314   3 3
314   4 8
314   5 8
314   2 8
314   3 8
```

Thanks!

Comment: There's no way to tell how the records should be matched up - the only thing I can see is that each "column" should be in descending order.  If there's another way to "match" records please add that to your question.

Comment: Is there another column that you're not showing? One that determines the order records are displayed in? There's not enough information in your query results to match columns with just what you've shown.

Comment: fthiella actually answered this but using MySQL as database. [link] (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/858b5/2) I tried to use it in Access with the actual fields but it won't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very hard problem in Access because you are joining on the ranks of the two columns.  Here is one approach, although it is not particularly efficient:

```
SELECT Query1.col1, Query1.col2, Query2.colB
FROM (select q.*,
             (select count(*)
              from query1 as q2
              where q2.col2 >= q.col2 and q2.col1 = q.col1
             ) as seqnum
      from Query1 as q
     ) as query1 INNER JOIN
     (select q.*,
             (select count(*)
              from query2 as q1
              where q1.colB >= q.colB and q1.colA = q.colA
             ) as seqnum
      from Query2 as q
     ) as Query2
    ON Query2.col1 = Query1.colA and
       Query2.seqnum = Query1.seqnum;
```

This construct is much easier in other databases, such as SQL Server where you can use the `row_number()` function.

Also, this version works assuming you have no duplicate values in the two columns.  With duplicates, you would need some other column to uniquely identify each row (an id or creation date, for instance).

Comment: Thanks Gordon but Access prompts me to enter parameter value in q2.col2. Also I'm trying to edit my question to replace ON Query2.col1 = Query1.colA to ON Query2.colA = Query1.col1 but I could not.

Comment: I think I got the colA, colB, col1, and col2 backwards between the tables.

Comment: I adjust the query accordingly but I still prompt for parameter. Are you sure it will work in Access?

Comment: @user2377055 . . . Are the subqueries assigning the ranks (`seqnum`) correctly?  Run them individually to see if they are working.

Comment: Was able to fix the ranks. col2 in the sample output is correct (in descending order) but i got different values in colB. Although I got correct results when I run them individually.

Comment: Does your book covers this type of query?

Comment: @user2377055 . .  . It covers using SQL for many different types of problems needed to answer business questions.  The focus is more on the business question and how to answer them using data (via SQL) than on SQL constructs.